# how to get the type of current pop-up keyboard

Tags: ios

I want to add a button when the keyboard is type of numberpad,but remove buttn if it's other type,how to get to know the type the popping up keyboard?thanks.

Comment: check for the "keyboardType"  property of the textField/textView

Comment: hi i have uploaded my answer pls check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 if(textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad)
 {
     //add your button here
     UIButton *button =[[UIButton alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 298, 320, 206)];
     [self.view addSubview:button];
 }  
 else
 {
   //do what you want
  [button removeFromSuperView];
 }


    return YES;
}
```

before doing this don forget to add delegate to the Uitextfield